# Could I use Qpyton as a library to interpreter a necessary python subroutine?

Tags: qpython, qpython3

I have an APP which needs a python lib to support.

So I would like to retrieve qpython in order to execute python.

Is there anyone has tried to do it before?

I am finding a way to retrieve the part of Qpython to serve my purpose, instead of execute on its ternimal; and, finally get the execution result back to my APP.

Thanks~

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could call the QPython's OPEN API,

http://www.qpython.org/en/guide_extend.html